# GradCam applied to video sequence classification with TimeDistributed CNN and LSTM

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network, lstm

after days working on it, I have found any reasonable way of doing, so here I am.
I have a network that aims to predict the next video class, given the features of the current one. Each video is composed by 30 frames. The idea is to apply a feature extraction method to each input, then feed into an LSTM + Dense layer to make prediction.
Here the code:

```
video = Input(shape=(30,299,299,3))
inc = InceptionV3(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(299, 299, 3))
cnn_out = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(inc.output)
cnn = Model(inputs=inc.input, outputs=cnn_out)
encoded_frames = TimeDistributed(cnn)(video)
encoded_sequence = LSTM(128, activation='relu', return_sequences=False, kernel_initializer=he_uniform(), bias_initializer='zeros', dropout=0.5)(encoded_frames)
hidden_layer = Dense(1024, activation='relu', kernel_initializer=he_uniform(), bias_initializer='zeros')(encoded_sequence)
outputs = Dense(4, activation="softmax", kernel_initializer=glorot_normal(), bias_initializer='zeros')(hidden_layer)
model = Model(inputs=[video], outputs=outputs)
adam = Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, amsgrad=False)
model.compile(optimizer=adam, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I would like to visualize the feature activations at the CNN stage for each image. So if I look at the saliency map for each input image I can understand which features are more importante than others to make this kind of prediction. 
All the examples on internet are facing with just one CNN and one input image, is there any way of doing this?
Any help is really appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Do you want to plot the activation map of the layers ? if so you can use https://github.com/philipperemy/keract

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes I know the package, but the thing Is that I have no ability to take the gradients at each time step generated from the cnn, sequentially. I would like to apply a sort of grad cam to each image at each time step. But yes, I want to plot the activation map of a desired layer. If you see at the code above, the time distributed layer hide the gradients of each time steps, so I am not able to retrieve them. I am trying to implement now in tensorflow2 which gives more suitable tools for this kind of stuffs.